# How to resolve linker error in C++ when compiling the body of a class in Dev C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the body of a class that I got from my e-book after designing the header file, but I am getting this error message:

> [Linker error] c:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-svn/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
>
> file: C:\Users\Chuks Joe\Desktop\collect2.exe
>
> Message:[Error] ld returned 1 exit status

The header file is in a separate file called dice.h and the class body in another separate file called called dice.cpp. The client program is in a separate file too called testdice.cpp.

How do I arrange these files and where do I put the .so file so that they can all be linked together for my program to run.

The compiler I am using is *[Dev-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B)*.

Comment: Dev-C++ is not a compiler

Comment: Just make sure you created the class correctly and on the top of the cpp add #include "dice.h"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Not a duplicate, this is a very specific instance where the issue is that the program is not "complete" in the sense that it has no `main()` or `winMain()` entry point.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell without seeing the code. You can have a look at how the linker works in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/401200). In your case, the error most likely comes from one of:

- you are trying to use a function or method you declared in the header file, but forgot to define in the source file.
- you are calling the linker with only the object file for `testdice` and forgot the object file for `dice`.
- is the undefined function yours? if not, you most likely need to add external libraries to the linker.

To narrow it down, try to use other functions defined in `testdice.cpp`. If that results in more linker errors, you are most likely not linking everything together. If it doesn't add more errors, you most likely forgot to define the function, or the prototype is slightly different in the source file and the header file.

Answer (score 0):

For your code to be linkable as an executable it must have either a `main()` (or `WinMain()` for GUI programs) entry point.  A class on its own is not a complete program in C++ - execution starts from the `main()` function.

For some reason, even for non-GUI apps the MinGW linker will complain about absence of `WinMain()` rather than `main()` but either will resolve the link.

You must normally provide the `main()` or `WinMain()` function, the exception being when you are using an application framework (usually GUI) that provides it internally.

In most cases to use a class you must instantiate an object of that class and invoke its member functions through that instance.  Static member functions do not need an object instance.

Example:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "dice.h"

int main()
{
    cDice myDie ;
    std::cout << "Throw = " << myDie.roll() ; 
}
```

Comment: thanks pals for your assistance so far. 
the class is now working. but the new problem am having now is that the class implementation and the program am trying to run must be in the same file before it can work.
so please, what should I do?

Comment: @ChuksJoeOrjiakor:  What you should do perhaps is post a new question. However you might avoid that by searching on *"separate compilation and linking"*.

Comment: Hi boss, I have done just what you suggested and I will so much appreciate your comment on that post. Thanks